# InputStream for Rar Files

Tags: java, android, rar

I am writing a comic book reader for android. I wanted my reader to read cbr files(cbr files are just rar files). So I looked and I found [Raroscope](https://github.com/radarsh/raroscope). I liked it because it has a lot of the same functions as ZipFile and ZipEntry. But my problem is I can't use it to get a inputstream from the rar file. I was wondering if there was something out there that i could use with Raroscope to get an input stream from the rar file.

this is how my code scans the rar

```
public class ReadCBR {

String mFileName;
List<String> mPages;
RARFile mCBR;

public ReadCBR(){

}

public void read(String filename){
    mFileName = filename;
    try {
        mCBR = new RARFile(filename);
        mPages = new ArrayList();
        Enumeration<? extends RAREntry> entries = mCBR.entries();

        while (entries.hasMoreElements()){
            RAREntry entry = entries.nextElement();
            mPages.add(entry.getName());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is what I want to be able to do

```
public Bitmap getPage(int pageNum, int maxLength){
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    InputStream in = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    in = mCBR.getInputStream(mPages.get(pageNum))


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [junrar](https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar) handle rar files in java. After extracting, you can get an input stream into a file.

Comment: I've tried junrar I get dependency errors with android. I've been told it doesn't work with the android log.

Comment: Also I would like to scan the files first. I don't want to decompress until i need the bitmap. that way i save on memory.

Answer (score 0):

mCBR = new RARFile(filename);

I think you have passed file name only as a parameter if so then you should pass file object or absolute path of the file not just only file name.

i.e.

Suppose your file is stored in the root of storage,

File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);

mCBR = new RARFile(file); // passing by file

OR

mCBR = new RARFile(file.getAbsolutePath()); // passing absolute path

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. ive gotten it to work using junrar but its very slow too slow for the application i'm trying to make